# My Xen VM on the EC2, choosing right AKI

Tags: amazon-ec2, xen, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I'm trying to move my Xen domU (guest VM) to the **EC2**.

On my machine I have a *Xen* (*dom0* and several *domUs*).
However, when I boot a guest VM, I use a kernel image from *dom0* 
(in the .*cfg* file lines *kernel=/...; initrd=/...*).
That means, my kernel image is not on the same disk that I use for VM.

So far so good.

Now, I would like to move my guest *VM* to the **EC2**.
I adjusted my */etc/fstab* (bundle, upload, register, run) and for the kernel image (*aki*) I used the default one.
Of course, my *VM* could not be started.
I tried several others (*aki*) and the same thing.

I assume that the problem is in my kernel image location?

I read somewhere that on the **EC2** I can use my own custom kernel.
So I download 2.6.35.4 (I'm running 2.6.26).
Compiled it, bundled it ... (I followed http://ec2-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/user_specified_kernels.pdf).

However, I still cannot boot my own image.

I have no problems to run an existing AMI (community).
The problem is to run my own VM (I have too much of setup to do it from vanilla AMI). 
Is this possible at all (I'm new in the EC2)?

Did I miss something?
Are there some guidelines/tutorials?
I'm running Debian Lenny (guest machine as well as base).

Comment: Read this and first comment http://www.niftiestsoftware.com/2011/09/24/converting-a-virtualbox-vm-to-an-ec2-ami/